# Initialize my class with array syntax

Tags: c#, .net, class, oop, constructor

Is there anyway to initialize my class like an array or a dictionary, for example

```
    private class A
    {
        private List<int> _evenList;
        private List<int> _oddList;
        ...
    }
```

and say

```
A a = new A {1, 4, 67, 2, 4, 7, 56};
```

and in my constructor fill _**evenList** and _**oddList** with its values.

Comment: select the even values for the evenList and the odd values for the oddList

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To use a [collection initializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb384062.aspx), your class has to:

- Implement `IEnumerable`
- Implement appropriate `Add` methods

For example:

```
class A : IEnumerable
{
    private List<int> _evenList = new List<int>();
    private List<int> _oddList = new List<int>();

    public void Add(int value)
    {
        List<int> list = (value & 1) == 0 ? _evenList : _oddList;
        list.Add(value);
    }

    // Explicit interface implementation to discourage calling it.
    // Alternatively, actually implement it (and IEnumerable<int>)
    // in some fashion.
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException("Not really enumerable...");
    }
}
```

Comment: are you sure that i can use this: new A {1, 4, 67, 2, 4, 7, 56}; with that

Comment: @AlexanderLeyvaCaro: Are you sure that you can't? (Hint: try it.)

Comment: And if i was use the dictionaty syntax, how is it?

Comment: @AlexanderLeyvaCaro: What do you mean by "dictionary syntax"?

Comment: like this: new A {{1,3,5},{2,4,6}}

Comment: @AlexanderLeyvaCaro: You'd need overloads of `Add` for the right number of arguments... or `public void Add(params int[] values)`

Comment: thanks very much, It is so simple and i did not know.

Comment: I see the link that you give me, but it don't cover this explanation

Comment: @AlexanderLeyvaCaro: Yes it does - under "Collection initializers". For more details, you'd probably be best off reading the specification...

Answer (score 0):

The only way that I can think of would be to pass your array through the constructor

```
private class A
{
    private List<int> _evenList;
    private List<int> _oddList;

    public A (int[] input)
    {
        ... put code here to load lists ...
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
A foo = new A({1, 4, 67, 2, 4, 7, 56});
```

Comment: @JonSkeet, It is true, one does learn something new everyday, if one keeps their mind open. I withdraw my answer as Jon's appears to far superior.